# Get the time between different timestamps based on a particular condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this table:

```
user_id | status  | timestamp
--------+---------+--------------------
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:01:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:02:00
7461    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:03:00
null    | open    | 2022-05-05 01:04:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:05:00
null    | on hold | 2022-05-05 01:06:00
8474    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:07:00
null    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:08:00
null    | solved  | 2022-05-05 01:09:00
```

I need to find the time difference between from when a user_id is assigned and the first status change. Also, if there is no status change until the next user is assigned, then I need to find the time difference from when the first user_id is assigned to when the next user_id is assigned.

The output I'm looking for is

```
user_id | timestamp
--------+----------
7461    | 00:01:00
8474    | 00:02:00
```

Could a CTE be used? Making a separate table with data that is needed and calculating the difference? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using a Snowflake database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(user_id) over (order by timestamp) as grp,
        lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as next_ts
    from T
)
select
    min(user_id) as user_id,
    min(timestamp) as start_time,
    coalesce(
        min(case when status is not null then timestamp end),
        max(next_ts)
    ) as end_time
from data
group by grp
```

Your data doesn't seem to show an example of the case with no status change/update. It also then isn't clear how you'd want to handle the case where that happens when the end of data is reached.

As I don't have access to Snowflake I'll let you deal with the issue of calculating and displaying the difference between the two times.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e6354448c6142d0493141b4d67477f73