# Calculate handling time per user for every ticket based on timestamps and status changes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have one table.

```
user_id | ticket_id | status  | timestamp
null    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:01:00
null    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:02:00
7461    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:03:00
null    |   1234    | open    | 2022-05-05 01:04:00
null    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:06:00
null    |   1234    | on hold | 2022-05-05 01:09:00
8474    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:10:00
null    |   1234    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:11:00
null    |   1234    | solved  | 2022-05-05 01:12:00
2638    |   1245    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:13:00
null    |   1245    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:16:00
5721    |   1245    | null    | 2022-05-05 01:17:00
```

I need to find the handling time for each user i.e. the time difference from when a user_id is assigned and the first status change. Also, if there is no status change until the next user is assigned, then I need to find the time difference from when the first user_id is assigned to when the next user_id is assigned.

The output I'm looking for is

```
user_id | ticket_id  | timestamp
7461    |   1234     | 00:01:00
8474    |   1234     | 00:02:00
2638    |   1245     | 00:04:00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I've tried and it works in MySQL. But I cannot use MySQL in this case.

```
   SELECT t1.user_id, t1.ticket_id
      MIN(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp))) AS timestamp
FROM tab t1
INNER JOIN tab t2
       ON t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
      AND t1.user_id IS NOT NULL
      AND t2.status IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.ticket_id
```

Comment: Is the actual question, how to convert an integer value (as returned by timestampdiff) to a timestamp value?

Comment: This is the same as your late question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220250/get-the-time-between-different-timestamps-based-on-a-particular-condition
you example data is even the same

Comment: It appears that the solution posted in other post was postgres specific (looking at posted fiddle there) and @Nuy_guy4631 is not able to port same to snowflake equivalent.  Though same question should have been used to seek further answers specific to snowflake.

Comment: @Pankaj okay, I'm sorry. I'm new to this. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used similar query to wht is posted in question, with a few additions  -
Used qualify to select top row for each user_id
Ignore rows with NULL timestamp difference.
Used TO_TIME to convert integer value returned by timestampdiff back to time value.

```
with data_cte (user_id,ticket_id,status,timestamp_1) as
(select * from values
(null,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:01:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:02:00'::timestamp),
(7461,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:03:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,'open','2022-05-05 01:04:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:06:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,'on hold','2022-05-05 01:09:00'::timestamp),
(8474,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:10:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,null,'2022-05-05 01:11:00'::timestamp),
(null,1234,'solved','2022-05-05 01:12:00'::timestamp),
(2638,1245,null,'2022-05-05 01:13:00'::timestamp),
(null,1245,null,'2022-05-05 01:16:00'::timestamp),
(5721,1245,null,'2022-05-05 01:17:00'::timestamp)
), cte_1 as
(
select
a.user_id,
a.ticket_id,
a.status,
a.timestamp_1 ts1,
b.timestamp_1 ts2
from data_cte a
left join
data_cte b
on a.timestamp_1 < b.timestamp_1
and
(b.status != nvl(a.status,'0') and b.status is not null)
or
(a.timestamp_1 < b.timestamp_1
and a.user_id != b.user_id)
)
select user_id, 
ticket_id, 
to_time(''||timestampdiff(second,ts1,ts2)||'') f -- to convert int value from timestampdiff to time.
from cte_1
where user_id is not NULL and f is not NULL
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id order by f asc) < 2  -- to select top row for each user_id
order by f;
```

| USER_ID | TICKET_ID | F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7461 | 1234 | 00:01:00 |
| 8474 | 1234 | 00:02:00 |
| 2638 | 1245 | 00:04:00 |